# Load JSON Data into Table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm trying to hit a REST API I've made and dump the returned data into a simple table using React.

I understand that I can hit my API and get the JSON data using this line:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v0.1/Organisations').then(r=>r.json());
```

If I add a `.then(d=>console.log(d));` I get the data showing up in the log, so I know my API is successfully returning the data:

[image: Data]

However, when I launch the application, I'm getting `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` on the `getKeys` function of my component.

I'm assuming, this is because the promise returned by `fetch` hasn't been fulfilled yet but I don't know how to wait for it.

My component definition:

```js
export default class Table extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.getHeader = this.getHeader.bind(this);
        this.getRowsData = this.getRowsData.bind(this);
        this.getKeys = this.getKeys.bind(this);
    }

    getKeys = function(){
        return Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    }

    getHeader = function(){
        var keys = this.getKeys();
        return keys.map((k,i)=>{
            return <th key={k}>{k}</th>
        })
    }

    getRowsData = function(){
        var items = this.props.data;
        var keys = this.getKeys();
        return items.map((r,i)=>{
            return <tr key={i}><RenderRow key={i} data = {r} keys={{keys}}/></tr>
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.getRowsData()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
const RenderRow = (props) =>{
    return props.keys.map((k,i) => {
        return <td key={props.data[k]}>{props.data[k]}</td>
    })
}
```

And my app.js:

```js
import './App.css';
import './components.js'
import React from 'react';
import Table from "./components";




function App() {
    var data = fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v0.1/Organisations').then(r=>r.json());
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v0.1/Organisations').then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>console.log(d));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Vaultex Tech Test</h1>
        <h2>Organisations</h2>
        <Table data={data}/>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm new to React, usually work on the back-end, so if I'm missing some sort of fundamental concept pointing that out would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add some statehandling for fetching stuff async. Example:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
```

```
//Adding a state placeholder for your result
const [myData, setMyData] = useState();
//Adding a loading state
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

//Add an async load function that resolves your endpoint
const load = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v0.1/Organisations');

  setMyData(data.json());
  setLoading(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
  //this will trigger your load function once when the component is mounted
  load();
}, []);

if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

return <Table data={myData} />;
```

Comment: Yes, state handling is the way to go. Thsorens was faster with the answer. I'd like to leave the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-demo-s8lv6?file=/src/App.js) here to see fetching in action.